# Prime ring with zero divisors Has Nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence

Undergraduate Algebra by Matej Bresar, Exercise 2.104: Prove that a prime ring with zero divisors contains a non-zero nilpotent.

Attempts:

By the definitions, 
$\forall a, b \in R-\{0\}, \exists x \in R\; s.t. axb \ne 0$

Let $c, d \in R-\{0\}, c^2, d^2 \ne 0, cd=0, c^2d^2=0 $

$\exists y \in R  \;s.t. \;c^2yd^2 \ne 0, c^2y, yd^2 \in R$

$(c^2yd^2)^2=c^2yd^2c^2yd^2=c^2(yd^2c^2y)d^2$

$yd^2c^2y=1, d^2c^2=y^{-2}, y^2=c^{-2}d^{-2} $ then $c^2(yd^2c^2y)d^2=c^2d^2=0 $

$(cd)^{-1}=d^{-1}c^{-1}, (dc)^{-1}=c^{-1}d^{-1}, c^{-1}(dc)^{-1}d^{-1}=c^{-2}d^{-2}$

Also,

$\exists y' \in R  \;s.t. \;cy'd \ne 0, cy', y'd \in R$

$(cy'd)^2=cy'dcy'd=c(y'dcy')d$

$y'dcy'=1, dc=y'^{-2}, y'^2=c^{-1}d^{-1} $ then $c(y'dcy')d=cd=0 $

$dcy'=y'dc, dcy'^2dc=dc$

I couldn't proceed further from here.

Comment: In what context did you find this problem?

Comment: From Undergraduate Algebra by Matej Bresar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are way off in the weeds. This is especially the case because there is no justification for $c$ or $d$ to have an inverse.

The argument should simply be:

---

If $ab=0$ for nonzero $a$ and $b$, then by definition of primeness, $bRa\neq \{0\}$, so $bxa\neq 0$ for some $x$.

Then $bxa$ is a nonzero element whose square is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,b$ be non-zero, zero divisors: $ab=0$. Since $R$ is prime, there exists $x\in R$ such that $axb\neq 0$.

If
$$(axb)^2=0$$
we are done.

Otherwise, assume that $(axb)^2\neq 0$. Since $(axb)^2=(axb)(axb)$, this implies that
$$ba\neq 0.$$

So, consider $(ba)^2=baba=b0a=0$. This is nilpotent.

Comment: How exactly did you get $ba \ne 0$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $ba=0$, then $(ax)(ba)(xb)=0$.

Comment: Ah I see. By contradiction. Thanks a lot!